# Inserting multiple documents with mongodb in a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, es6-promise

Inserting multiple documents with mongodb in the same request I'm getting undefined value.

```
.post(function (req, res) {
    ...
    Item.create(data)
    .then(function (item) {

        var modelOtherItem;            

        OtherItem.create({
            ...
        }).then(function (otherItem){
            modelOtherItem = otherItem; 
            modelOtherItem; // here I get the expected value       
        });

        res.status(201);

        res.json({
            item: item, // has a value
            otherItem: modelOtherItem // -> is undefined
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises **return immediately** but their `then` callbacks execute asynchronously. That means you are accessing `modelOtherItem` **before it's assigned a value**. The easiest fix would be to add your code inside the `then` callback (you can also get rid of the `modelOtherItem` variable):

```
post(function (req, res) {
  // ...
  Item.create(data)
  .then(function (item) {

    OtherItem.create({
        // ...
    }).then(function (otherItem){            

        // add code here
        res.status(201);

        res.json({
          item: item, // has a value
          otherItem: otherItem // also has value
        });     
    }); 
});
```

One thing to note that you can create all of your items with one call by passing an array to `Model.collection.insert(array...` or, if using Mongoose, `Model.create(array...`

---

#### Alternative solution

If you models can be created independently of one another (meaning that creation of any item doesn't depend on any other item), you can use the [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method that takes an array of promises and resolves once all of the promises in that array resolve as well:

```
post(function (req, res) {
  // ...

  // create an array that will hold item creation promises
  let promises = [];

  // add the promise that creates the item
  promises.push(Item.create(...));

  // add the promise that creates the other item
  promises.push(OtherItem.create(...));

  Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function(results) { // this function is called once all promises in the array `promises` resolve
    // results contains the resolved data from each promises in the array
    // in the order of the promises

    var item = results[0];
    var otherItem = results[1];

    // OR you can use ES6 `let` declaration with 
    // destructuring to achieve the same as above
    // in a cleaner way:
    // let [item, otherItem] = results;

    res.status(201);

    res.json({
      item: item,
      otherItem: otherItem
    });  

    // in ES6, if both the object property name and the variable name are the same
    // you can just specify the name once and achieve the same effect as above
    // with less code:
    /*
    res.json({
      item,
      otherItem
    });  
    */
  });
});
```

Comment: @Jordi glad to help :)